# Having trouble with including PHP file

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to include `header.php` file inside my `index.php` file, both of them are in the same folder. However, it is not working.

Here's how I coded **index.php** file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css" />

    <title>Bootstrap</title>
</head>
<body>
    <? php include 'header.php'; ?>
    <p>the header file should be above this line</p>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">3</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">2</div>
            <div class="col-md-4">1</div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!-- Optional JavaScript -->
<!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's how I coded my **header.php** file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>HEADER INCLUDED</p>
    <p>HIP HIP HORRAH!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I expected that when I open **index.php** in Chrome, I should see something like

```
HEADER INCLUDED  
HIP HIP HORRAH!  
the header file should be above this line  
--- the column ---
```

But the first two lines are not showing up. I am confused what I am missing here.

Comment: Perhaps the opening tag shouldn't have a space like `<?php` and not `<? php`?

Comment: You jave a space in the opening php tag. Beside that the resulting html document does not seem to be valid.

Comment: oh yeah! it worked!

Comment: Why are you including a complete HTML document inside another HTML document?

Comment: although it looks like a complete html file, I saved it as .php, also, I want to make this portion dynamic later on.

Comment: It's still a complete HTML document, regardless of the file extension. When you get the include to work (by fixing the typo the answer below mentions), you will get nested HTML documents, which isn't valid HTML. If you remove everything from the header file except what's between the body tags, your set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<? php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

To:

```
<?php include 'header.php'; ?>
```

As `<?php` means starting of PHP code. But, `<? php` does not mean anything and is a parse error.

As `php` is not a language construct like: `for`, `foreach`, `while`, etc...

Comment: `<? php` does not have to be a parse error. If you do not have `short_open_tags` set to On it should just be outputted as a string in HTML and because it starts with `&lt;` the browser will interpret it as a tag that will be ignored.

Comment: @AthanasiusKirchner, this is the error generated: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'include' (T_INCLUDE) in /in/bOCXL on line 1

Comment: in the environment of your code sample `short_open_tag` is set to on, see https://3v4l.org/Z4dOU. If it is set to "Off" `<? php include 'header.php'; ?>` will just be outputted as a string.
It is a bit of a guess, but some could read the description of ganjaam in this way, when he writes `But the first two lines are not showing up.`. That does not sounds like a parse error, but may be the question is just not precise enough.
Anyway your fix is correct and I just wanted to show that there may be another unintended behaviour.